# UIDocumentInteractionController overlaps statusbar in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, statusbar

I have an iPad app that I'm migrating to iOS 7. Most of the 'issues' with the statusbar have been solved but sadly one remains.
When I open a PDF document using the UIDocumentInteractionController I get my nice document preview. But when I tap on the pdf to get the statusbar for the "Open with..." dialog and the close button. It overlaps with the statusbar.

[image: UIDocumentInteractionController statusbar overlap]

I tried using the edgesForExtendedLayout method. But the UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't accept it. 
How do I prevent the statusbar from overlapping the UIDocumentInteractionController view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found new solution.

In info.plist file add this for iOS 7:
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance (View controller-based status bar appearance) = NO

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling on this for iOS8, like me: It appears that the problem is flipped in iOS8. You need to **remove** the *UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance* key from info.plist for the status bar to look right in UIDocumentInteractionController.

Implement *prefersStatusBarHidden* on each UIViewController as needed.

At least this worked for me, this time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your view controller is presented modally?

If that is the case the only solution I found is to:

- embed your view controller in a navigation controller
- present the navigation controller modally
- in documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview return the navigation controller instead of the view controller

That will push the UIDocumentInteractionController instead of presenting it as a fullscreen modal VC and will not screw up your view controller.

Comment: As suggested by powpow I provided the Navigation controller as the UIDocumentInteractionController's viewcontroller. This worked in a sense that the preview is then pushed onto the nav controller and the statusbar looks good! However I don't use an Navigation Controller everywhere, and in a UISplitview the preview only covers the part of the screen.